# Get close window button in asp.net C#(server side)

Tags: c#, server-side

I want to get the [browser] close button event in my web app.
I know how to get it client side by javascript but there are some problems within.
Is it possible to get this event server side in my web app?

Thanks

Comment: You want to know that a browser window has been closed, but you don't want to use JavaScript? Not possible.

Comment: what happens when you close your web app windown? I want to do some functions when I close that button, so I want the event...

Comment: @Oded: exactly. I know to get the event in body unload event but there were some prbs. by the way, I didn't find ways in server side mode. I wanted to be sure...thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Can't be done through server code, but you can add some code on your server-side event which adds `<script type="text\javascript">window.close();</script>` when it finishes.

Have a look at [ClientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/btf44dc9.aspx).